# Are append operations on an AppendBlob atomic?

Tags: azure, atomic, azure-blob-storage

I am using append blob to store a large binary file. I've got the file in parts (every part is less than 4 MB) and append them to make it whole again. If an append operation fails during the process, are there any remains on the file from this failed append attempt? Or this append operation is atomic?

Comment: Are you using `Append Blobs` or doing a chunked upload on a `Block Blob`?

Comment: AppendFromStreamAsync on AppendBlob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the storage service returns a failure code, nothing remains from the failed attempt. This assumes 'attempt' means a single storage service call (ex append 4MB block).

Answer (score 1):

With an `Append Blob`, as soon as you write a block to the blob it gets committed and changes the size of the blob. So in your scenario, let's say you've broken the source file in 10 parts and appending these parts. Let's further assume 1st - 4th part succeed, 5th part fails and then 6th - 10th part succeeds. In this case you will have a corrupt blob with parts 1-4 and 6-10. Because in an Append Blob, contents are always appended to the existing content of the blob, you would have no way to insert correct data for 5th part.

Considering this scenario, **I would not recommend using `Append Blobs`**. The use case for an Append Blob is definitely not this. **I would recommend using `Block Blob` for this**. With the Block Blob, you put 1st - 4th part and then 5th part fails then the whole upload operation will fail. With Block Blobs, Azure Storage keeps the uploaded yet uncommitted chunks for 14 days. So if you want to resume the upload from 5th part, you would get information about uncommitted chunks from Azure and then restart your upload from 5th part. Once the remaining parts are uploaded, you can instruct Azure to put these chunks together (using Put Block List operation) to create the blob.

Comment: If it throws an exception when the 5th part fails, then there is no problem. I will try to append the 5th part before the 6th. Is it OK in this case?

Comment: With Append Blobs, you can't. The content is always added to the end of the blob. So if 5th fails and 6th succeeds then essentially 6th part becomes the 5th part in the blob and then when you upload 5th part, it becomes the last part in the blob.

Comment: I am not trying to append 6th before getting a success from 5th.

Comment: Ahh ... so if I understand correctly, if 5th fails you're failing the operation. Am I correct? But still my answer holds true. As soon as 1st part is uploaded for an Append Blob, a persistent blob is created in Azure Storage for you.

Comment: If 5th fails, I am not cancelling the whole operation. I am retrying to append 5th until it succeeds. Then I continue with 6th and so on. What I am concerned is possible remains of the failed attempts if any.

Comment: Nothing remains from the failed attempt.

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft Could you write that as an answer