# Is UploadFromStream function of CloudBlockBlob atomic for sizes less than 64 MB?

Tags: azure, stream, azure-blob-storage, atomic

I am reading a file from BlockBlob. File size is guaranteed to be less than 64 MB. Therefore it is single block operation. After reading the file, I am changing some parts of it and re-uploading it via UploadFromStream function of CloudBlockBlob. My question is "Is UploadFromStream function of CloudBlockBlob atomic for sizes less than 64 MB?". Is there a possibility that I have a corrupt file on azure storage after an exception during write process?

Note: I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293815/are-append-operations-on-an-appendblob-atomic) for AppendBlobs and got an answer that it is atomic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's atomic if it's under 64MB, unless you parallelize as parallelizing will chunk the data. Even for data greater than 64MB with block blobs, there's a two step commit process so if upload fails in the middle you're still in relatively good shape. If we upload chunks of data in 4MB blocks, we also have to commit these blocks. So, if uploading fails we won't commit and all you'll have is some extra uncommitted blocks only accessible via the get block list operation (aka, they uncommitted blocks are not downloadable). So, for block blobs upload failing in the middle won't overwrite your existing data or corrupt it in general.